# Determine which group(s) a running process is in?

Tags: linux, permissions, process, group, proc

I'm trying to determine which group(s) a **running** child process has inherited. I want to find all groups the process is in given its uid. Is there a way to determine this via the `/proc` filesystem?

Comment: Are you looking for the groups associated to the process's UID (which one?), or for the groups that the process is in? The two are usually the same, but they might not be (e.g. if the process was run with `sudo -g`, or if the group database changed since the user logged in).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The list of groups is given under `Groups` in `/proc/`<pid>`/status`; for example,

```
$ grep '^Groups' /proc/$$/status
Groups: 4 24 27 30 46 110 115 116 1000
```

The primary group is given under `Gid`:

```
$ grep '^Gid' /proc/$$/status
Gid:    1000    1000    1000    1000
```

`ps` is also capable of showing the groups of a process, as the other answers indicate.

Comment: **best-practice is to use `ps` command when possible instead of opening/reading/parsing files under /proc/pid/ because the files and contents of files under /proc/pid can change whenever the kernel version changes**. for example: i had a script that worked on kernel version 3.x and then the same script failed on 5.x kernel version. i changed the script to use `ps` and now it works in both kernel version 3.x and 5.x.

Answer (score 14):

For the effective group id, real group id and supplementary group ids (as used for access control):

```
ps -o gid,rgid,supgid -p "$pid"
```

`gid` and `rgid` are fairly portable, `supgid` less so (all 3 would be available with the `ps` from procps as typically found on Linux-based systems).

`group`, `rgroup` and `supgrp`  can be used to translate group ids to group names, but note that for group ids that have several corresponding group names, only one of them will be shown (same as for `ls -l` vs `ls -n` or anything that deals with user or group names based on ids).

For the process group id (as used for terminal job control):

```
ps -o pgid -p "$pid"
```

To store it into a variable:

```
pgid=$(($(ps -o pgid= -p "$pid")))
```

Comment: For parsing, it's helpful to omit the output of the header; `-o pgid=` will do that. `-p` is optional and can be left out. There's still leading whitespace in the output, so do this to capture the PGID: `pgid=$(ps -o pgid= "$pid" | grep -o '[0-9]\+')`

Comment: @Ingo, `-p` is not optional per POSIX. Neither `-o` nor `\+` are standard either. Here, you could use `pgid=$(($(ps -o pgid= -p "$pid")))` portably if you wanted to store that pid in a variable (gives 0 if `$pid` is not found but preserves the exit status of `ps`).

Comment: Thanks for adding the parsing part into your answer, and for the notes on POSIX compatibility; that `$((...))` evaluation is a really neat trick (and also slightly more efficient that using `grep`). I'm learning so much from your great answers!!!

Answer (score 6):

Using `ps`:

```
$ ps -o group,supgrp $$
GROUP    SUPGRP
muru     adm,cdrom,sudo,dip,www-data,plugdev,lpadmin,mlocate,sambashare,lxd,libvirtd,docker,muru
```

From [`man ps`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ps.1.html), the output columns used for `-o`:

```
   egid        EGID      effective group ID number of the process as a
                         decimal integer.  (alias gid).

   egroup      EGROUP    effective group ID of the process.  This will be
                         the textual group ID, if it can be obtained and
                         the field width permits, or a decimal
                         representation otherwise.  (alias group).

   gid         GID       see egid.  (alias egid).

   group       GROUP     see egroup.  (alias egroup).

   supgid      SUPGID    group ids of supplementary groups, if any.  See
                         getgroups(2).

   supgrp      SUPGRP    group names of supplementary groups, if any.  See
                         getgroups(2).
```

Answer (score -3):

On a UNIX system derived from SVr4, you may call:

```
pcred <prcess-id>
```

Note that the official `procfs` is not ASCII but binary.

Comment: The question is about Linux, which is not (much) derived from SVr4, so this doesn't answer the question. Also there is no such thing as “the official procfs”: each Unix variant has its own implementation of it, or doesn't have one.

Comment: You seem to miss that there was a paper on procfs and another one on procfs-2.  Linux has not much more in common with that paper than the name procfs. Since this portal is about UNIX, it is obvious that there are people who like to know how things work on UNIX even thought the question might have been Linux specific.